# Kubernetes v1.29.1 installation issue with kubeadm init

Tags: kubernetes

Cluster information:

Kubernetes version:

Installing on Virtual machine;

Installation method: kubeadm

Host OS: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

CNI and version: NA
CRI and version:

Docker Engine - Community Version: 24.0.7

containerd: Version: 1.6.27

I have Installed docker, cri-dockerd and kubelet kubeadm kubectl

started initiating the cluster with the below cmd

kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr 10.244.0.0/16 --apiserver-advertise-address=HOSTIP --cri-socket=unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock

getting ERROR:

[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.29.1
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
[ERROR CRI]: container runtime is not running: output: time=“2024-01-19T09:11:55Z” level=fatal msg=“validate service connection: validate CRI v1 runtime API for endpoint "unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock": rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing: dial unix /var/run/cri-dockerd.sock: connect: connection refused"”
, error: exit status 1
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal with --ignore-preflight-errors=...
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher

Docker and containerd daemons are running, but the kubelet is not running.
kubelet Error:
: E0118 10:11:36.691366 2383 run.go:74] “command failed” err="failed to load kubelet config file, path: /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml, error: failed to l>
: kubelet.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
: kubelet.service: Failed with result ‘exit-code’.
: kubelet.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 9

swap is deactivated,
file /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml is available in the location with the right permissions.

Comment: As per the [github link](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/issues/4581), use the command `rm /etc/containerd/config.toml` and restart the containerd. Once it is done, initiate the cluster using `kubeadm init` command.

Comment: @KiranKotturi Thank you for your time.

I was able to resolve this by fixing the cri-docker.service, reinstalled them.
https://github.com/Mirantis/cri-dockerd

Comment: Thanks for your response,you can post the resolution steps as an answer for the better visibility of the community.